# Existence of harmonic symplectic structure on a symplectic manifold (which is cohomologue to the initial symplectic structure)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Assume that  $(M, \omega)$  is  a  symplectic  manifold which is  equiped with a  Riemannian  metric.

Is there  a  symplectic structure $\omega '$  which is a harmonic  $2$-form? Can one  choose such a  $\omega'$  such that it would  be  de  Rham cohomolgue to the  initial  form $\omega$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A difficulty with your question is that there need not be any relation between the given symplectic form $\omega$ and the given Riemannian metric $g$; consequently, it is far from clear that (some symplectic form cohomologous to) the symplectic form $\omega$ can be $g$-harmonic, or that there exists a $g$-harmonic symplectic form for that matter.

Let's assume first that $\omega$ and $g$ *are* 'related', namely that they are adapted to each other *i.e.* there is an almost complex structure $J$ such that $\omega(-, J-) = g(-,-)$ and $\omega(J-,J-) = \omega(-,-)$. Then it turns out that $\omega$ is co-closed for $g$, hence $g$-harmonic; see for instance Theorem 1 in Delanoë's *[Analyzing non-degenerate 2-forms with riemannian metrics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086902800111)*. It is well-known that the set of metrics adapted to a given symplectic form is non-empty, hence given $\omega$, there is always several choices of $g$ for which $\omega$ is harmonic. (In dimension 2, a simple calculation shows that a symplectic form is $g$-harmonic if and only if it is adapted to $g$, and your questions are thus always answered positively.)

If we drop the condition that $\omega$ and $g$ be adapted, then it is possible (in dimension 4 and higher) that the answers to your questions be negative. To be more specific, in dimension 4, given a symplectic form $\omega$, there is always a choice of $g$ for which the $g$-harmonic form cohomologous to $\omega$ is not symplectic; If moreover $b_2 = 1$ (*e.g.* $M = \mathbb{C}P^2$), then for the same $g$, *no* harmonic form is symplectic. (By taking cartesian products, I suspect one can get counter-examples in higher dimensions too).

Here is a proof of the above claims. The Luttinger-Simpson(-Perutz-Taubes) theorem implies that any 4-manifold which admits a symplectic structure admits cohomologous nonsymplectic 'nearly symplectic' forms; see Theorem 1 of this [paper of Taubes](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2006/0013/0004/MRL-2006-0013-0004-a006.pdf) for a more precise statement. Now, according to Proposition 1 in this [paper of Auroux-Donaldson-Katzarkov](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.gt/1513799611), any nearly symplectic form is $g$-harmonic for some metric $g$. The combination of these two results and the uniqueness of the harmonic form in its cohomology class yield the claims.

Answer (score 1):

Hodge's theorem states that on a closed Riemannian manifold, any closed form has a unique harmonic representative. So the answer to your question is yes, and moreover it is unique, provided this harmonic representative is nondegenerate (as a bilinar form). But that is not always the case (e.g. when $\omega$ is exact, $\omega' = 0$). I don't know whether there is a way to predict that the harmonic representative of $\omega$ will be degenerate or not.

Comment: Thank  you  very much  for  your  answer  and  your  attention to my question. The  main motivation for  the  question was the  Hodge theorem, but the  nondegeneracy is  the  main question

Comment: I  think that the  unique ness is  up to coboundary.  For example in $\mathbb{R}^2$  let  $let \omega= e^x dx\wedge dy$. In this  example $\omega$ is exact but one  can put $\omega'=dx\wedge  dy$ a  nondegenerate  harmonic  2-form.

Comment: @Seub The "counterexample" you provide is irrelevant - a symplectic form on a closed manifold is never exact. So the nondegeneracy question remains open.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval  I  think the  symplectic  form on a COMPACT manifold is never exact, right?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes. When I say a "closed manifold", I mean compact with no boundary.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval  My  apology, I  did  not  pay  attention to the word "Closed", sorry.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: good point. Amitai: If your question is about the nondegeneracy of the harmonic representative of a symplectic form, then you should just write that.

Comment: @Seub Hey, I am not OP in this case. Just wanted to draw your attention to this point.